# Low level C - Display text, pixel by pixel

Tags: c, text, low-level

I am working on a small project where I have to write a low level app. I'd like to display text in that app, and I would even like it to be anti aliased (à la ClearType). No libraries allowed, I have to draw each char pixel by pixel.

What is the best way to do this? Can you recommend some known algorithms? How should I store/read the fonts?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you at least use a library to read the fonts?

Comment: You'll have to change "small project" to "large project" for that.

Comment: You are basically asking how to make a font renderer like FreeType or ClearType from scratch?

Comment: Ruslik: I already have necessary routines to draw a Pixel on the screen. Isn't it easy to create some sort of char map and apply some sort of AA?
Ignacio: Nope. I can hard code them into the app, though. Kos: Err, a very basic one, with hard coded fonts and not very good AA. I have some routines to draw a pixel @ x, y coord, I am asking where to go from there. It shouldn't be very difficult.

Comment: and device drivers and a operating system?

Comment: Perhaps instead of anti-aliased, you mean a grayscale or color bitmap font? If you want to use real (truetype) fonts, your "small project" has indeed just become not just a "large project" but a "huge project". :-)

Comment: Chris: Already taken care off. It's for a windows 98 app, no protected mem. access, already have coded some graphical mode routines. It'll run fullscreen, using ms-dos emulation.

Comment: Monospaced fonts are easy, but they don't require any AA. TrueType fonts that can benefit from it uses bezier curves. There is huge difference between them.

Comment: R: The font should be a bitmapped. Anti aliasing should be very basic and can look sort of crude.

Comment: Francisco, you should be able to use the libraries like FreeType to do what you want (render letters to a byte array) so that you can copy them to your screen pixels. The libs have a lot of functionality like sub-pixel antialiasing for LCDs. You should seriously consider to go for one of those.

Comment: ruslik: I can hardcode font data into the app, perhaps mapping each pixel. The AA would be simply adding some gray in corners, etc.

Comment: Kos: Proof of concept for a college project. I do not want to use libs, since it would devalue my project.

Comment: You should be aware that unless you're willing to spend 6 months or so researching rendering requirements for all the world's languages, refusal to use libraries greatly devalues your project in that you've basically decided it can only be used with English (and possibly a small number of other Western languages, assuming they're written with precomposed characters).

Comment: Adding some sort of font smoothing sounds like yak shaving to me. If you want smoother bitmap fonts just use gray-scale bitmaps instead of monochrome bitmaps.

Comment: R: College project. Undergrad. Nobody will ever use/see this code again. Just some brain flexing to get credit. Nali: Part of the challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean you just want to smooth the edges of an existing bitmapped font? This is easy if your original font is 16x32 and you want to render it at 8x16 or something like that, but if you don't have a higher-resolution bitmap to begin with, smoothing is a highly nontrivial operation involving a lot of guesswork. In that case, I would lookup the `2xsai` algorithm (which gives visually-pleasing results for this kind of thing) and first perform it to upscale the font to double resolution, then scale it back down with a area-averaging algorithm (i.e. take each destination pixel from the average of a 4-pixel square).

I would also recommend saving your final "anti-aliased" bitmap font and simply using it in your program, rather than performing all this work at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would you recommend storing the bitmapped font? Bidimensional array of booleans?

Comment: An array of booleans would not only be very inefficient, but unable to store grayscale which is what you need. Try an array of `uint8_t`. If you're happy with fixed font size, just make it `uint8_t font[96][16][8];` for an 8x16 pixel font with 96 glyphs (U+0020 to U+007F). Otherwise I'd just use a pointer and treat it as a one-dimensional array, using your own arithmetic for addressing dimensions.

Comment: I am thinking about hardcoding a B&W font and on runtime render it for some different sizes (grayscale).

Comment: Unless your original font is very high resolution or happens to be a power-of-2 multiple of the final desired size, rescaling will look pretty damn ugly. If you want to do this, make the original 128x256 or so and use area-averaging for the downscale (weighting the pixels that are only halfway in the box down accordingly). This will be rather slow.

Comment: Also, unless you're really tight on memory, I would still use full bytes for each pixel, with values 0 and 255, rather than just bits/bools. This makes your scaler code more uniform - both input and output are 8-bit grayscale bitmaps.

Comment: No need to worry about performance. As I said, just a toy app. Well, complicated algorithms. Will have a lot of work on my hands.

Comment: Maybe you understand this yourself... but scaling with e.g. 2xsai won't give you nearly as good a result as with e.g. ClearType. Font rendering is really a science, especially if you want things to be legible at small sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Putting all together:

There are two main types of fonts:

1) Monospaced: all the characters have fixed size, and you define a bitmap for each. No need for Anti Aliasing (you can hardcode the grey levels in the bitmap). Look horrible when resized.

2) True Type: each letter is defined by a set of parameters for Bezier curves. Can be easily scaled to any size, but requires lots of program logic (and processing power!) for that. Anti Aliasing is useful here (and especially the sub-pixel rendering techniquies).

As I see you want to use bitmapped font and rescaling? You could just precompute several of them, thus avoiding complex runtime logic.

As R. suggested, keeping the bitmaps at higher resolution in greyscale instead of BW will help. I'd suggest using size that is divisible by most small numbers, so that the bitmap can be downscaled easily. Also, if this resolution is high enough, then you can keep it in BW and downscale to greyscale (using surface integral).

EDIT: feel free to edit it and please don't vote. Just put all those commentaries together.

Comment: Truetype fonts can be monospaced :P I think the word you're looking for is bitmapped. What I want is an algorithm to resize bitmapped fonts so they won't look terrible (kinda sorta AA) PS: Since this is only a proof of concept, I'll probably leave it to runtime.

Comment: Err, you mean bitmapped and vectorial? There are monospaced vectorial fonts (Courier*, ...), PostScript fonts are vectorial fonts.

Comment: ...Also non-monosaced bitmap fonts exist.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to build a good font engine, especially if you need to do scaling and anti-aliasing. So I suggest you take the easy path:

1. Decide on the fonts and sizes you want to use.
2. Generate a bitmap font for every font/size combination you need to use. This can be done with a tool like [Bitmap Font Generator](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/).
3. Use the bitmap fonts in your program. Blitting bitmaps should be relatively easy.

If you want more features, I suggest you look into using an engine like [FreeType](http://www.freetype.org/) before trying to make your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, reading a TTF (or any other) font and rendering some glyph into the bitmap isnt *that* hard, given you know some stuff about rasterization and bezier curves. The bad point is that if you want the text to look good, it's gonna take a huge amount of code. Aliased font is pretty hard to render, I'm not talking about hinting. There needs to be a routine for kerning, multi-character sequences, something that decides which glyphs map to your characters and also encoding stuff, ...

You might want to use a bitmap font, which comes pre-rendered - then the whole rendering operation is a simple image copy, eventually with some resampling or rotation; but well, you lose the vector font features.

My advice is to take FreeType and live with it, it's a nice library just for this, and can be statically linked and stripped of unnecessary bloat very easily.