# Algorithms for downscaling bitmapped fonts

Tags: c, algorithm, text, low-level, smoothing

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179414/low-level-c-display-text-pixel-by-pixel).

I am working on a low level C app where I have to draw text. I have decided to store the font I want to use as an array (black and white, each char 128x256, perhaps), then I'd downscale it to the sizes I need with some algorithm (as grayscale, so I can have some crude font smoothing).

Note: this is a toy project, please disregard stuff like doing calculations at runtime or not.

Question is, **which algorithm?**

I looked up `2xSaI`, but it's rather complicated. I'd like something I can read the description for and work out the code myself (I am a beginner and have been coding in C/C++ for just under a year).

Suggestions, anyone?

Thanks for your time!

Edit: Please note, the input is B&W, the output should be smoothed grayscale

Comment: Forget I mentioned 2xSaI. It's a powerful *upscaling* algorithm you could use to get from low-resolution pixellated font glyphs to higher-resolution ones, but if you have nice high-resolution glyphs to begin with then you don't need it for anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figure out the rectangle in the source image that will correspond to a destination pixel. For example if your source image is 50x100 and your destination is 20x40, the upper left pixel in the destination corresponds to the rectangle from (0,0) to (2.2,2.2) in the source image. Now, do an area-average over those pixels:

- Area is 2.2 * 2.2 = 4.84. You'll scale the result by 1/4.84.
- Pixels at (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), and (1,1) each weigh in at 1 unit.
- Pixels at (0,2), (1,2), (2,0), and (2,1) each weigh in at 0.2 unit (because the rectangle only covers 20% of them).
- The pixel at (2,2) weighs in at 0.04 (because the rectangle only covers 4% of it).
- The total weight is of course 4*1 + 4*0.2 + 0.04 = 4.84.

This one was easy because you started with source and destination pixels lined up evenly at the edge of the image. In general, you'll have partial coverage at all 4 sides/4 corners of the sliding rectangle.

Don't bother with algorithms other than area-averaging for downscaling. Most of them are plain *wrong* (they result in horrible aliasing, at least with a factor smaller than 1/2) and the ones that aren't plain wrong are a good bit more painful to implement and probably won't give you better results.

Comment: Also look at ruslik's answer. If you use very-high-resolution source images (for example, 10x as large as your destination), you can forget about partially-included pixels and just round to whole-pixel rectangles, and still get very good results.

Comment: I think your math is a little off - for a range of 0.0 to 2.2 the source would need to be 44x88, not 50x100. Other than that I agree this gives an acceptable result. The other algorithms you mention can give better results when done properly, although most naive implementations suffer from the problems you describe.

Answer (score 3):

Consider that your image is a N*M BW bitmap. For simplicity we'll consider it `char Letter[N][M]`, when allowable values are `0` and `1`. Now consider that you want to downscale it to the `unsigned char letter[n][m]`. This will mean that each greyscale pixel from `letter` will be computed as number of white pixels in the big bitmap:

```
char Letter[N][M];
unsigned char letter[n][m];
int rect_sz_X = N / n; // the size of rectangle that will map to a single pixel
int rect_sz_Y = M / m; // in the downscaled image
int i, j, x, y;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) for (j = 0; j < m; j++){
    int sum = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < rect_sz_X; x++) for (y = 0; y < rect_sz_Y; y++)
        sum += Letter[i*rect_sz_X + x][j*rect_sz_Y + y];
    letter[n][m] = ( sum * 255) / (rect_sz_X * rect_sz_Y);
};
```

Note that the rectangles that creates pixels could overlap (in case when sizes aren't divisible). The larger is your original bitmap, the better.

Comment: Ideally you should compute partial overlaps with proper weights like in my answer, but if the source image is very high resolution compared to the destination, it won't matter.

Comment: This is completely wrong when `N` isn't evenly divisible by `n` (or `M` by `m`), because the error accumulates as you go toward the end. Consider N=100 and n=51 for example; rect_sz_X=1, so the last output pixel (at i=50) will be taking input pixel 50, not input pixel 99.

Comment: P.S. The code could be fixed, but the output would still look lumpy unless the input was much larger than the output, by at least 16x.

Answer (score 2):

Scaling a bitmapped font is the same problem as scaling any other bitmap.  The general class of algorithm that you're after is *interpolation*.  There's quite a few ways to do this - in general, the more visually accurate the result, the more complicated the algorithm.  You could start by looking at (in increasing order of complexity):

- [Nearest-neighbour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation)
- [Bilinear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation)
- [Bicubic interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation)

Comment: These are all very bad choices for *downscaling*. For upscaling, bilinear and bicubic are half-decent.

Comment: Yep, avoid interpolation. While it's good for natural images, artificial images like text looks horrible after such transformatons.

Comment: @ruslik: It's not an issue of natural vs artificial images. It's an issue of skipping sample points. Downscaling to a factor smaller than 1/2 with bilinear or bicubic interpolation is essentially first doing a nearest-neighbor downscale to twice the destination size, then using interpolation to go the final step. Naturally this aliases horribly and looks hideous, but that doesn't stop lots of popular image-viewer software from doing it... :-(

Comment: @R, you're correct but it's because the algorithms are misinterpreted. When you're downscaling, the filter should be widened proportionally to the amount of scaling. You're implementing a filter, and the filter needs to take out frequencies based on the smaller of the two images, input or output. When the input is smallest then nothing needs to scale.

Comment: Indeed.  If you're downsampling then you need to apply a low-pass filter first, to remove spatial frequencies that are above the Nyquist limit of the output size.  This will have the effect of smearing adjacent pixels into each other, which will mean that information isn't lost / "skipped".

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple.  If all you've got is a bitmapped font instead of an outline font then you have very limited choices in picking an anti-aliasing pixel color.  For example, if the bitmapped font point size is exactly four times as large as the desired display point size then you can only ever get 16 distinct choices.  The number of 'lit' pixels in the 4x4 mapping rectangle.

Having to deal with fractional mapping is a programming exercise but not one that improves the quality.

Answer (score 0):

If it is acceptable to constrain the downscaling to multiples of 2 (50%, 25%, 12.5%, etc.), then a very simple and fairly good algorithm is to create each downscaled pixel as the majority vote of all the source pixels.  For example, at 50%, a square of four pixels are forming the one downscaled pixel:  if zero or one of them is on, then the output is off; if three or four are on, then the output is on.  The artistic case (for two pixels on), either always choose on or off, or look at other surrounding pixels for tiebreaking.

Comment: See OP's earlier question. He wants "anti-aliased" fonts. Your algorithm will just put him back where he started, with ugly black/white pixellation.

Comment: I don't think the anti-aliased or grayscale requests were there when I read the question.