# Algorithm for drawing thick antialiased lines

Tags: graphics, drawing

Are there any "standard" algorithms for drawing thick antialiased lines?  I have found Xiaolin Wu's algorithm for drawing 1px width lines, but have yet to find any extension for thicker lines.

Comment: I found an implementation here in javascript: http://members.chello.at/easyfilter/bresenham.js

I copied it to a github gist for posterity: https://gist.github.com/randvoorhies/807ce6e20840ab5314eb7c547899de68#file-bresenham-js-L813

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your lines will always be straight and you aren't looking to anti-alias curves, you can do a three-pass approach.

I'm not sure how efficient this would be in your environment, but you can draw the aliased version of the line with `thickness - 2` and then use Xiaolin Wu's approach twice to anti-alias the edges. @Francisco P.'s approach would work, too, and might actually be preferable.

One way or another, the aliasing needs to be smoothed out along the outer edges. If you're dealing with lines of thickness greater than one, you can achieve this by just drawing the two edges anti-aliased and then filling in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

An inneficient, crude, quick way would be to draw the lines larger (say, 4x) and then scaling them down using weight averaging. Details here:

[Algorithms for downscaling bitmapped fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179905/algorithms-for-downscaling-bitmapped-fonts)

Look at the accepted answer.

Comment: Hah, thanks but I suppose I should have replaced the word "standard" with "efficient, and reasonably elegant" in my question.

Comment: Well, I might have undermined my efforts, but this is a pretty standard way to do what you're asking.

Comment: I think it comes down to a trade-off between CPU and memory. Doing multiple passes would likely be more computationally expensive than downscaling, but downscaling would be likely require more memory for the higher resolution. On top of that you have the CPU processing to shrink the line. In the end both approaches would probably perform the same on a desktop machine, but if we're talking about cell phones it might make a difference. Either way I think your recommendation is more mainstream.

Answer (score 1):

A good and fast solution based on my [Rasterizer library](https://github.com/foo123/Rasterizer) that uses Wu's algorithm for thin lines (`xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax` are the boundaries of the viewport used for clipping).

The algorithm draws the outline of the thick line using Wu's line algorithm for thin lines and then fills the inside by splitting it in two triangles and filling each one with a fast algorithm.

```
/*
given line's thickness w and dx,dy of line, wx, wy are computed as:
n = hypot(dx, dy)
w2 = (w-1)/2
wx = dy*w2/n
wy = dx*w2/n
*/

function wu_thick_line(set_pixel, xs, ys, xe, ye, dx, dy, wx, wy, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
{
    var t, sx, sy,
        wsx, wsy,
        xa, xb, xc, xd,
        ya, yb, yc, yd;

    if (xs > xe)
    {
        t = xs;
        xs = xe;
        xe = t;
        t = ys;
        ys = ye;
        ye = t;
    }

    sx = 1;
    sy = ys > ye ? -1 : 1;

    if (is_strictly_equal(dx, 0))
    {
        return fill_rect(set_pixel, stdMath.round(xs - wx), stdMath.round(ys), stdMath.round(xs + wx), stdMath.round(ye), xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax);
    }
    if (is_strictly_equal(dy, 0))
    {
        return fill_rect(set_pixel, stdMath.round(xs), stdMath.round(ys - wy), stdMath.round(xe), stdMath.round(ys + wy), xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax);
    }

/*
      wx      .b
    +-----.(s)  .
wy  |.a  |  .     . f
       . |    .     .
 dy      |.     .     .
         |  .g    .     . d
         |    .     .(e)
         +----- .----
             dx  c

a: ys + wsy - ys = -(x - xs)/m => x = xs - m*wsy: (xs-wsx, ys+wsy)
b: ys - wsy - ys = -(x - xs)/m => x = xs + m*wsy: (xs+wsx, ys-wsy)
c: ye + wsy - ye = -(x - xe)/m => x = xe - m*wsy: (xe-wsx, ye+wsy)
d: ye - wsy - ye = -(x - xe)/m => x = xe + m*wsy: (xe+wsx, ye-wsy)
*/

    wsx = sx*wx;
    wsy = sy*wy;

    xa = xs - wsx;
    ya = ys + wsy;
    xb = xs + wsx;
    yb = ys - wsy;
    xc = xe - wsx;
    yc = ye + wsy;
    xd = xe + wsx;
    yd = ye - wsy;

    // outline
    wu_line(set_pixel, xa, ya, xb, yb, null, null, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax);
    wu_line(set_pixel, xb, yb, xd, yd, null, null, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax);
    wu_line(set_pixel, xd, yd, xc, yc, null, null, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax);
    wu_line(set_pixel, xc, yc, xa, ya, null, null, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax);
    // fill
    fill_triangle(set_pixel, xa, ya, xb, yb, xc, yc, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax);
    fill_triangle(set_pixel, xb, yb, xc, yc, xd, yd, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax);
}
function wu_line(set_pixel, xs, ys, xe, ye, dx, dy, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
{
    var xm = stdMath.min(xs, xe), xM = stdMath.max(xs, xe),
        ym = stdMath.min(ys, ye), yM = stdMath.max(ys, ye);

    // if line is outside viewport return
    if (xM < xmin || xm > xmax || yM < ymin || ym > ymax) return;

    if (null == dx)
    {
        dx = stdMath.abs(xe - xs);
        dy = stdMath.abs(ye - ys);
    }

    // clip it to viewport if needed
    if (xm < xmin || xM > xmax || ym < ymin || yM > ymax)
    {
        var clipped = clip(xs, ys, xe, ye, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax);
        if (!clipped) return;
        xs = clipped[0];
        ys = clipped[1];
        xe = clipped[2];
        ye = clipped[3];
    }

    if (is_strictly_equal(dx, 0) || is_strictly_equal(dy, 0))
    {
        return fill_rect(set_pixel, stdMath.round(xs), stdMath.round(ys), stdMath.round(xe), stdMath.round(ye));
    }

    // Wu's line algorithm
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm
    var x, y,
        x1, x2,
        y1, y2,
        xend, yend,
        gradient = 0,
        intersect = 0,
        fpart = 0,
        rfpart = 0,
        gap = 0,
        e = 0.5,
        steep = dy > dx;

    if (steep)
    {
        x = xs;
        xs = ys;
        ys = x;
        x = xe;
        xe = ye;
        ye = x;
        x = dx;
        dx = dy;
        dy = x;
    }
    if (xs > xe)
    {
        x = xs;
        xs = xe;
        xe = x;
        y = ys;
        ys = ye;
        ye = y;
    }

    gradient = (ys > ye ? -1 : 1)*dy/dx;

    // handle first endpoint
    xend = stdMath.round(xs);
    yend = ys + gradient * (xend - xs);
    gap = 1 - (xs + e - stdMath.floor(xs + e));
    x1 = xend;
    y1 = stdMath.floor(yend);
    fpart = yend - y1;
    rfpart = 1 - fpart;
    if (steep)
    {
        set_pixel(y1, x1, rfpart*gap);
        set_pixel(y1 + 1, x1, fpart*gap);
    }
    else
    {
        set_pixel(x1, y1, rfpart*gap);
        set_pixel(x1, y1 + 1, fpart*gap);
    }

    intersect = yend + gradient;

    // handle second endpoint
    xend = stdMath.round(xe);
    yend = ye + gradient * (xend - xe);
    gap = xe + e - stdMath.floor(xe + e);
    x2 = xend;
    y2 = stdMath.floor(yend);
    fpart = yend - y2;
    rfpart = 1 - fpart;
    if (steep)
    {
        set_pixel(y2, x2, rfpart*gap);
        set_pixel(y2 + 1, x2, fpart*gap);
    }
    else
    {
        set_pixel(x2, y2, rfpart*gap);
        set_pixel(x2, y2 + 1, fpart*gap);
    }

    // main loop
    if (steep)
    {
        for (x=x1+1; x<x2; ++x)
        {
            y = stdMath.floor(intersect);
            fpart = intersect - y;
            rfpart = 1 - fpart;
            if (0 < rfpart) set_pixel(y, x, rfpart);
            if (0 < fpart) set_pixel(y + 1, x, fpart);
            intersect += gradient;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (x=x1+1; x<x2; ++x)
        {
            y = stdMath.floor(intersect);
            fpart = intersect - y;
            rfpart = 1 - fpart;
            if (0 < rfpart) set_pixel(x, y, rfpart);
            if (0 < fpart) set_pixel(x, y + 1, fpart);
            intersect += gradient;
        }
    }
}
function clip(x1, y1, x2, y2, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
{
    // clip points to viewport
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liang%E2%80%93Barsky_algorithm
    var p1 = -(x2 - x1),
        p2 = -p1,
        p3 = -(y2 - y1),
        p4 = -p3,
        q1 = x1 - xmin,
        q2 = xmax - x1,
        q3 = y1 - ymin,
        q4 = ymax - y1,
        rn2 = 1, rn1 = 0,
        r1, r2, r3, r4;

    if ((p1 === 0 && q1 < 0) || (p2 === 0 && q2 < 0) || (p3 === 0 && q3 < 0) || (p4 === 0 && q4 < 0))
    {
        // parallel to edge and outside of viewport
        return;
    }
    if (p1 !== 0)
    {
        r1 = q1/p1;
        r2 = q2/p2;
        if (p1 < 0)
        {
            if (r1 > rn1) rn1 = r1;
            if (r2 < rn2) rn2 = r2;
        }
        else
        {
            if (r2 > rn1) rn1 = r2;
            if (r1 < rn2) rn2 = r1;
        }
    }
    if (p3 !== 0)
    {
        r3 = q3/p3;
        r4 = q4/p4;
        if (p3 < 0)
        {
            if (r3 > rn1) rn1 = r3;
            if (r4 < rn2) rn2 = r4;
        }
        else
        {
            if (r4 > rn1) rn1 = r4;
            if (r3 < rn2) rn2 = r3;
        }
    }

    // completely outside viewport
    if (rn1 > rn2) return;

    return [
    x1 + p2*rn1, y1 + p4*rn1,
    x1 + p2*rn2, y1 + p4*rn2
    ];
}
function fill_rect(set_pixel, x1, y1, x2, y2, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
{
    // fill a rectangular area between (x1,y1), (x2,y2) integer coords
    var x, y;
    if (x1 > x2)
    {
        x = x1;
        x1 = x2;
        x2 = x;
    }
    if (y1 > y2)
    {
        y = y1;
        y1 = y2;
        y2 = y;
    }
    if (null != xmin)
    {
        if (x2 < xmin || x1 > xmax || y2 < ymin || y1 > ymax) return;
        x1 = stdMath.max(x1, xmin);
        y1 = stdMath.max(y1, ymin);
        x2 = stdMath.min(x2, xmax);
        y2 = stdMath.min(y2, ymax);
    }
    if (y1 === y2)
    {
        for (x=x1; x<=x2; ++x) set_pixel(x, y1, 1);
    }
    else if (x1 === x2)
    {
        for (y=y1; y<=y2; ++y) set_pixel(x1, y, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        for (y=y1; y<=y2; ++y)
        {
            for (x=x1; x<=x2; ++x) set_pixel(x, y, 1);
        }
    }
}
function fill_triangle(set_pixel, ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
{
    // fill the triangle defined by a, b, c points
    var x, xx, t,
        y, yb, yc,
        xac, xab, xbc,
        yac, yab, ybc,
        zab, zbc,
        clip = null != xmin, e = 0.5;
    if (clip)
    {
        if (stdMath.max(ax,bx,cx) < xmin || stdMath.min(ax,bx,cx) > xmax || stdMath.max(ay,by,cy) < ymin || stdMath.min(ay,by,cy) > ymax) return;
    }
    if (by < ay) {t = ay; ay = by; by = t; t = ax; ax = bx; bx = t;}
    if (cy < ay) {t = ay; ay = cy; cy = t; t = ax; ax = cx; cx = t;}
    if (cy < by) {t = by; by = cy; cy = t; t = bx; bx = cx; cx = t;}
    yac = cy - ay;
    if (is_strictly_equal(yac, 0))
    {
        // line or single point
        y = stdMath.round(ay);
        x = stdMath.round(stdMath.min(ax, bx, cx));
        xx = stdMath.round(stdMath.max(ax, bx, cx));
        return fill_rect(set_pixel, x, y, xx, y, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax);
    }
    yab = by - ay;
    ybc = cy - by;
    xac = cx - ax;
    xab = bx - ax;
    xbc = cx - bx;
    zab = is_strictly_equal(yab, 0);
    zbc = is_strictly_equal(ybc, 0);
    y = stdMath.round(ay + e);
    yb = by;
    yc = stdMath.round(cy - e);
    if (clip) {y = stdMath.max(ymin, y); yc = stdMath.min(ymax, yc);}
    for (; y<=yc; ++y)
    {
        if (y < yb)
        {
            if (zab)
            {
                x = ax;
                xx = bx;
            }
            else
            {
                x = xac*(y - ay)/yac + ax;
                xx = xab*(y - ay)/yab + ax;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (zbc)
            {
                x = bx;
                xx = cx;
            }
            else
            {
                x = xac*(y - ay)/yac + ax;
                xx = xbc*(y - by)/ybc + bx;
            }
        }
        if (stdMath.abs(xx - x) < 1)
        {
            if (!clip || (x >= xmin && x <= xmax)) set_pixel(stdMath.round(x), y, 1);
            continue;
        }
        if (xx < x)
        {
            t = x;
            x = xx;
            xx = t;
        }
        x = stdMath.round(x + e);
        xx = stdMath.round(xx - e);
        if (clip) {x = stdMath.max(xmin, x); xx = stdMath.min(xmax, xx);}
        for (; x<=xx; ++x) set_pixel(x, y, 1);
    }
}
```

Result (canvas line vs rasterizer line):

[image]